# MSAccess: Abbv Expansion - Most efficient approach?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access app where I pre-process a table of information (freeform descriptions) to expand known abbreivations against a standard.  The approach I am using works well enough for a few hunded, even a few thousand records, but really bogs down >10,000 records.

My abbv standard only currently contains only ~100 "Abbv Term" pairs in a Table, and it will expand greatly over time.  Small sample:

```
 Abbv   Expansion
 =====  =========
 BN     bone
 BNDG   bandage
 BPSY   biopsy
 BRN    brown

 " The quick BRN fox " would get expanded to " The quick BROWN fox "
 " The fox is BRN " would get expanded to " The fox is BROWN "

 Note: The desc is padded with a leading & trailing space in advance of the 
 Replace function. The result is trimmed at the end of the function.
```

The query I am currently using to perform the bump/expand/replace against the entire [Data] table:

```
 strSQL = "UPDATE Data, AbbvExpansion SET Data.Desc = Replace(Data.[Desc],' ' & AbbvExpansion.[Abbv] & ' ',' ' & AbbvExpansion.[Expansion] & ' ');"
 db.Execute strSQL
```

My approach seems too simplex/crude, especially at scale.  I'm looking for a smarter approach to accomplish this result.

Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: Are you storing the abbreviation as a field in the table? If so, why not use a join?

Comment: Yes, the table is [AbbvExpansion].  What would I perform the JOIN on to [Data]?  Abbreviations are embedded in Data.[Desc].

Comment: Your select statement would become `Select [Data].*, [AbbvExpansion].[Expansion] 
FROM [Data] INNER JOIN [AbbvExpansion] ON [Data].[Desc] = [AbbvExpansion].[Abbv]`

Comment: @MarkPelletier Does each value of `Data.Desc` consist of a single abbreviation with no additional text, or can there be additional text which must be preserved after the abbreviation is expanded?

Comment: Yes, Descriptions contain freeform text (many words), one or more of which might be abbreviated.  "This is a SMPL example" gets expanded to "This is a SIMPLE example" via expansion.  It's more a REPLACE function using a table as reference source.

Comment: @MarkPelletier Then a join won't work; your data isn't normalized.

Comment: Lynn, yes.  Inner Join won't work in this example.

Comment: Should *"The fox is BRN"* have expansion applied? How about *"The fox is BRN!"*?

Comment: I have padded the front and end of my desc with a ' ' to permit matches at the front and end of the string. " The fox is BRN ", replacing   " BRN " with " BROWN ".  I Trim() at the end of the function.  There is no punctuation in this data,

Comment: So then what you have now produces the correct result and the point of this question is to make it happen faster?

Comment: Hans, correct.  The function works fine as-is, but >10,000 records runs slowly, also as the Abbv list grows, will only get worse.  I am looking for a more efficient approach, thinking my approach is too crude.  I was thinking ARRAYS might be a path to follow, but I have very little experience there.

Comment: This is a challenging workload for Access.  I don't see how arrays would offer an improvement, but would be happy to be proven wrong.  Must you expand abbreviations in each of 10K+ rows on a repetitive basis, or can that scale of effort be limited to just the initial data load --- and then subsequent abbreviation processing is limited to new and modified records?

Comment: Hans, this is a one-time expansion, not a recurring task.  I can live with the current approach and delay.  There are ~2M records to be addressed, but I can probably mandate breaking the task into 10K chunks.